# Register a file thumbnail with the OS for an arbitrary file type

Tags: mime-types, thumbnails, preview, file-browser

Is there a way I can add some content to the top of my file (binary) that will display a thubmnail of the file (possibly also included in the binary file)? Alternatively is it possible to create some hidden file or directory which will map thumbnails to files for the OS/file browser?

I am really just interested in *nix for the time being. Also, I am not asking how to create a thumbnail, I am asking how to associate the thumbnail (or have the filebrowser read it from the file) under say Gnome or KDE, or MAcOS.

In case you're curious, I am working with very large 3D scientific data sets in the HDF5 format. The data sets are REALLY large and take FOREVER to generate, explore and render, and there are tons of them. It would be great to be able to browse them in the file browser with thumbnails which would allow the user (me and others) to preview--in low res--part of the data set to help decide which one to open. HDF5 provides some "user-block" space at the beginning of the file in which one could store an image or xml file, etc. Again, I can generate the thumbnail image, I need a way of telling the file browser where it is and that it should display the thumbnail.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write a plugin for the file manager of each desktop environment.

For GNOME, Nautilus is the assumed file manager. There are tons of previewers/thumbnailers available, so you can dissect one. Here's a simple MP3 cover art thumbnailer written in Python: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=114098

As for KDE and Mac OS, I am not so sure. KDE should be similar to GNOME when it comes to thumbnailing, but Mac OS is out of the scope of my knowlege. You'd have to code another plugin, I'd assume.